# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ejb/EJBObject

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, ejb

I'm trying to deploy servlet, but every time I run my controller I catch `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ejb/EJBObject`. I don't tnink that is useful to paste code there, because troubles lays in `lib`s, `jar`s and etc. I was trying to add `javaee-api-6.0.jar` and `j2ee.jar` to project(`WEB-INF/lib`), but `Tomcat6` says:

```
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\tomcat\tomcat6\webapps\deployAnother\WEB-INF\lib\j2ee.jar) - jar not loaded
. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Їхт 20, 2014 1:58:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\tomcat\tomcat6\webapps\deployAnother\WEB-INF\lib\javaee-api-6.0.jar) - jar
not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

`Tomcat7` says equal things. I though that adding `jar`s into `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib` is nice idea, but no.

*PS. I'm not using Maven*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a lot more than that to run EJBs in Tomcat.  It's a servlet/JSP engine, not a full blown Java EE app server like JBOSS.

If you want to continue you'll need [OpenEJB](http://tomee.apache.org/).

Comment: But I'm running JBoss while Tomcating.

Comment: Sorry, this makes no sense to me.  Yes, JBOSS uses Tomcat as its servlet/JSP engine, but it's built in.  All those JARs are in the JBOSS classpath.  You don't have to put JARs anywhere if you've packaged and deployed correctly.  If you have EJBs, you need to create an EAR file and deploy it to JBOSS>